# orderBy subcategories till exists in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

i want to order category as per below.

```
level-1
   level-11
       level-111
            level-1111
            level-1112
            level-1113
       level-112
       level-113
            level-1131
       level-114
       level-115
             level-1151
             level-1152
  level-12
       level-121
            level-1211
            level-1212
            level-1213
       level-122
       level-123
            level-1231
       level-124
       level-125
             level-1251
             level-1252
level-2
    .....<same as above if have nestied category than show in below line till have nested category>
level-3
```

in sort, I want category data till the existence of the child category. if a category has a child then shown in below line and child have child category then shown in below child till category doesn't have child.
how to order like that. I also want pagination of 10 rows .in the above example, the first page has data till   **level-114**    child.
hope my question is clear and understandable.

Comment: You can create relationships in models and then you can access in the controller.

Comment: but then how to do paginate and where I should applied that, because we don't know how many child categories exist and how many nested categories available